# Rename elements of character variable

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to suffix the elements in a character variable (a) with extension .TXT.  The following code appears to works well (as it renames all the elements  on terminal), but when I type the name of other variable (A) (which stores the modified names), only last element gets printed.

```
for(i in 1:length(a))
{
A<- paste (a[i],".TXT",sep="") 
print (A)
}
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop overwrites `A` at every iteration. What you want is `A` to be a vector, try that :

```
A = c()
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  A <- c( A, paste (a[i],".TXT",sep="") )
  print (A[i])
}
```

It creates `A` as an empty vector of length 0, then extends it with the modified elements of `a`.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you need a loop for this:

```
a <- LETTERS[1:5]
A <- paste0(a, ".TXT")
A
#[1] "A.TXT" "B.TXT" "C.TXT" "D.TXT" "E.TXT"
```

Comment: If he wants to print it, he needs a loop, but you got a good point.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
A <- as.character()
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  A[i] <- paste(a[i],".TXT",sep="")
}
A
```